# When could a linear discriminant give excellent or possibly even the optimal classification accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistical-ai

I am actually reading the linear classification. There is a question in the question set behind the chapter in the book as follows:

> Sketch two multimodal distributions for which a linear discriminant could give excellent or possibly even the optimal classification accuracy.

I have no idea about how to get the optimal solution on linear classification, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A linear model has a linear decision boundary. So in the case of the question, you need to draw two multimodal distributions whose domains do not overlap at all and then you can just say the linear model would should all to the right of some number would be class 1 and all to the left would be class 2